# Referring grandparent version in pom.xml from child pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, dependency-management

I have a multi module maven project. My parent pom.xml refers to the grandparent module that I don't administer with version X. Now a new version X+1 of this grandparent module with breaking changes was released. I'm wondering how can I make only child1 module to refer to X+1, while modules child2...childN to keep referring to X.

Structure:

```
/parent
    /child1
        pom.xml
    /child2
        pom.xml
    ...
    /childN
        pom.xml
    pom.xml
```

Parent pom.xml:

```
<version>${revision}</version>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>grandparent</artifactId> <!-- grandparent module that I don't administer -->
    <version>X</version> <!-- I want one of the children to refer to X+1 -->
</parent>

<modules>
    <module>child1-module</module>
    <module>child2-module</module>
    ...
    <module>childN-module</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <revision>A</revision>
</properties>
```

Every child pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
   <version>${revision}</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>child1</artifactId>
```

Comment: Obviously since maven doesn't allow having multiple parents, this is impossible to achieve in the form that you're asking... However, Could You describe what exactly are you getting from the parent pom (plugins, properties) and why don't you afraid of clashes that might be possibly introduced by grandparent of version X and of X + 1 (say in some 3rdparty library version) ? In general you could try to omit the parent altogether and use it as an aggregator pom, while keeping children inheriting from the grandparent directly... Another direction is using BOMs maybe

Comment: It's fine for me to completely ignore `parent` pom in `child1`, I copied all related dependencyManagement and pluginManagement stuff from `parent` to `child1`. Now my child1 pom looks like this

`<parent>`
   `<artifactId>grandparent</artifactId>`
    `<groupId>my.group</groupId>`
    `<version>X+1</version>`
    `<relativePath></relativePath>`
`</parent>`

Now my build is successful, but I cannot run the child1 module anymore because its Child1Application.java is outside of the source root.

Comment: What is `Child1Application`? Is it something Spring boot related maybe? And what is the source root?

Comment: Yes it's SpringApplication class

Comment: In this case `Child1Application` has to be in the child1 module, so if it gets compiled spring boot plugin should create an artifact from it so that you'll be able to run it. I'm not sure I understand what is 'source root' in this case. Maybe you can update the question and show schematically how does your child's pom.xml look like now, where exactly the Child1application is located and what is the error you see while trying to run the project + how do you run it actually?

Comment: If you don't have any dependencies on your parent, you can make your grandparent module as a parent module. woudln't this resolve your problem?